# How many topological spaces with finitely many points are path-connected?

Tags: general-topology, recreational-mathematics, path-connected

Here's a set-point topology question I thought of.

> How many topological spaces with $n$-points are path-connected?

Comment: For finite spaces, path-connected and connected are equivalent, which might make any argument easier.

Comment: @Randall Then I have a misunderstanding over what it means to be path-connected. Like, take the space with three points $x,y,z$ and topology $\{\{x,y,z\},\{x,y\}, \{x\}, \{y\}, \varnothing\}$. This space is certainly connected, but I don't see how you can have a continuous function $[0,1]$ to $\{x,y\}$ to connect $x$ and $y$ with a path.

Comment: Seems very unlikely to me that there's a nice closed formula.

Comment: @MikePierce: Try $f(t)=x$ for $t\in[0,1/2)$, $f(1/2)=z$, $f(t)=y$ for $t\in (1/2,1]$.

Comment: @EricWofsey AHH

Comment: My memory of JP May's work on the problem is that Eric is right:  it's essentially unsolvable.

Comment: Also, a former student of mine is a few doors down the hall from you...

Comment: The question in the title sounds different than the question below it. It seems you do not assume $T_1$, but if you did, then there is exactly one space with finitely many points that is path-connected, namely a singleton. (Should I say, up to a homeomorphism...) You may also read about the specialization (pre)order at the following link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_topological_space#Connectivity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this text by May](https://math.uchicago.edu/~may/FINITE/FINITEBOOK/FINITEBOOKCollatedDraft.pdf) for a proof that for finite topological spaces, path-connectedness and connectedness are equivalent.

I also believe there is no known formula for the number (non-homeomorphic or total) of such topologies on $n$ points as a formula in $n$. A search on the online [encyclopedia](http://oeis.org) didn't yield promising results so far.